# How to annotate a parameter as implicit in pattern match while extracting values

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, implicit

I have a class like

```
case class A(a: Int, b: String)
```

and a function

```
def f(a: Int)(implicit b: String) =???
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
val a = A(11, "hello")
a match {
  case A(a, implicit b) => f(a)
}
```

How can I make the parameter b implicit without explicitly declaring it after extraction.

Comment: Why make it implicit? If you want `f()` to receive the value of `b` then supply it explicitly: `f(a)(b)` The compiler will only look for an implicit if the parameter is not supplied explicitly.

Comment: @jwvh That I know :) just curious if it can be done.

Comment: Extractor for A has the following definition `def unapply(a: A): Option[(Int, String)] = Option((a.a, a.b))`. Not sure if it can be done without introducing new implicit wrapper for `b`

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but: You shouldn't have `implicit b: String` anywhere, ever. Create a wrapper. Create an `AnyVal`-class. Do anything, but don't have any `implicit String`s flying around in your code.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I have a proper value class for my type. This is just dummy example to understand if the solution exists. :)

Comment: @curious ok ok, proper value class sounds good ;) I don't think that something similar exists, because the matched variables are almost always one single character long, and `(a)` takes only 3 chars, whereas every other keyword like `implicit` with at least one additional space character would take three times as much space, without adding any real value... So, unless you use it *really* often, it's usually not worth it...

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't worry about passing the argument implicitly, since you can easily provide it explicitly in this particular case:

```
case class A(a: Int, b: String)

def f(a: Int)(implicit b: String) =???

val a = A(11, "hello")
a match {
  case A(a, b) => f(a)(b)
}
```

If you must pass the value implicitly, it needs to be declared in scope. For example:

```
a match {
  case A(a, b) => {
    implicit val s = b
    f(a)
  }
}
```

Also, as has been pointed out, don't use `implicit` with a common type. It's better if you wrap it in another class:

```
case class A(a: Int, b: String)

case class SomeCustomString(s: String)

def f(a: Int)(implicit b: SomeCustomString) =???

val a = A(11, "hello")
a match {
  case A(a, b) => {
    implicit val s = SomeCustomString(b)
    f(a)
  }
}
```

If you could explain the use case for the implicit argument, I could provide a better example.

**Update**: There is a kind of way to do what you want:

```
case class SomeCustomString(s: String)

case class A(a: Int, b: String) {
  implicit val s = SomeCustomString(b)
}

def f(a: Int)(implicit s: SomeCustomString) =???

val a = A(11, "hello")
import a._
f(a.a)
```

Or, if you must have it within a pattern match, that last bit would be:

```
a match {
  case x: A => {
    import x._
    f(x.a)
  }
}
```

**Update 2**: Or, as yet another approach (again, with `implicit` largely redundant):

```
case class SomeCustomString(s: String)

case class A(a: Int, b: String) {
  implicit val s = SomeCustomString(b)
  def invokeF = f(a)
}

def f(a: Int)(implicit s: SomeCustomString) =???

val a = A(11, "hello")
a.invokeF
```

or

```
a match {
  case x: A => x.invokeF
}
```

Does that help?